# How to programmatically connect 2 players in multiplayer match without presenting the default ViewController

Tags: ios, game-center, multiplayer

I am working on a real time multiplayer game in IOS using swift language. When I call the function "func findMatchWithMinPlayers(_ minPlayers: Int, maxPlayers: Int)" it shows the default ViewController where we have to invite other player and then the match starts.

Is there any way to do this without presenting the ViewController and to connect 2 players automatically or by ourself?

```
open class func findMatchWithMinPlayers(_ minPlayers: Int, maxPlayers: Int) {
    guard EGC.isPlayerIdentified else {
        EGCError.notLogin.errorCall()
        return
    }
    do {
        let delegatVC = try EGC.sharedInstance.getDelegate()


        EGC.disconnectMatch()

        let request = GKMatchRequest()
        request.minPlayers = minPlayers
        request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers


        let controlllerGKMatch = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
        controlllerGKMatch!.matchmakerDelegate = EGC.sharedInstance

        var delegeteParent:UIViewController? = delegatVC.parent
        if delegeteParent == nil {
            delegeteParent = delegatVC
        }
        delegeteParent!.present(controlllerGKMatch!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } catch EGCError.noDelegate {
        EGCError.noDelegate.errorCall()

    } catch {
        fatalError("Dont work\(error)")
    }
}
```

I have found this solution for programmatically matchmaking but it is in Objective -C

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;


[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        // Process the error.
    }
    else if (match != nil)
    {
        self.myMatch = match; // Use a retaining property to retain the match.
        match.delegate = self;
        if (!self.matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
        {
           self.matchStarted = YES;
           // Insert game-specific code to begin the match.
        }
    }
}];`
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your reference above, programmatically finding match and connecting to a specific match are both different processes. As per [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW1) official document of Apple, you will have to first find the match. This approach is for programmatically finding a match, and this finding match is not exactly creating a new match, if created for some other user, then would be assigned a slot to you.

```
        let request = GKMatchRequest()
        request.minPlayers = 2
        request.maxPlayers = 2
        GKMatchmaker.shared().findMatch(for: request, withCompletionHandler: {(match, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                // Process the error.

                print("Error finding match")
                print(error?.localizedDescription)

                self.show_match_error();




            }
            else if match != nil {


                self.myMatch = match!

                self.myMatch?.delegate = self


                // Use a retaining property to retain the match.

                if !self.matchStarted && self.myMatch?.expectedPlayerCount == 1
                {
                    self.matchStarted = true
                    // Insert game-specific code to begin the match.

                    print("Match Started")

                }


            }
            else
            {
                print("Match is nill")
            }

        })
```

Now if there's no error neither of network, nor of local player authentication, your `matchStarted` variable would become `true`. Now you must have to implement two methods of the delegate `GKMatchDelegate`. Here are these.

**#1**

```
//match state change
 func match(_ theMatch: GKMatch, player playerID: String, didChange state: GKPlayerConnectionState) {
    /*recall when is desconnect match = nil*/
    guard myMatch == theMatch else {
        return
    }

    switch state {
        /// Connected /
    case .stateConnected where myMatch != nil && theMatch.expectedPlayerCount == 0:
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

            lookupPlayers();


        }
        /// Lost deconnection /
    case .stateDisconnected:
        print("match disconnected")

        show_match_error();
        matchStarted = false;
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

**#2**

```
 // match state change error
func match(_ theMatch: GKMatch, didFailWithError error: Error?) {
    guard myMatch == theMatch else {
        return
    }

    guard error == nil else {
        print("Match failed with error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        myMatch?.disconnect()
        matchStarted = false;
        return
    }
}
```

These methods of the delegate will get you know about the process you did in the first method, in other words you tried to find a real time match for the local player. If without any failure you surpass the stage of creating and connecting to a player in the match, then call the methods `lookupPlayers();`.

The purpose of `lookupPlayers();` is simply escorting connected players with the match you just created, calling this method from the `finMatch( ..` completion handler, wouldn't work, so the match wouldn't expect to have players in it.

The delegate method `did Change State` will alarm you about the successful connection of the players. So, you definitely have to call `lookupPlayers()`.

```
 //lookup player
func lookupPlayers() {

        guard let match =  myMatch else {
           print("No Match")
            return
        }


        let playerIDs = match.players.map { $0.playerID }

        guard let hasePlayerIDS = playerIDs as? [String] else {
            print("No Player")
            return
        }

        //Load an array of players
            GKPlayer.loadPlayers(forIdentifiers: hasePlayerIDS) {
                (players, error) in

                guard error == nil else {
                   print("Error retrieving player info: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    self.myMatch?.disconnect()
                    return
                }

                guard let players = players else {
                    print("Error retrieving players; returned nil")
                    return
                }


                for player in players {
                        print("Found player: \(String(describing: player.alias))")
                }


                if let arrayPlayers = players as [GKPlayer]? { self.playersInMatch = Set(arrayPlayers) }

                GKMatchmaker.shared().finishMatchmaking(for: match)

                //(Static.delegate as? EGCDelegate)?.EGCMatchStarted?()

        }


  selectHost()

}
```

The method `selectHost()` is for selecting host for the match, because at the very first time, this host would send the data or in other words would start the game.

Sending and receiving the data is by these two methods.

```
 // send data
func sendDataToPlayers(data: Data!) {


    if(myMatch != nil && matchStarted)
    {

        let player = myMatch?.players;
        do {
            try myMatch?.send(data, to: player!, dataMode: GKMatchSendDataMode.reliable)
            } catch  {
                print("Sending failed")
                myMatch?.disconnect()
            }

    }



}
```

Use the delegate method for receiving the data.

```
// recieve data
func match(_ match: GKMatch, didReceive data: Data, forRecipient recipient: GKPlayer, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer) {

  // CHEERS  


}
```